# Как запушить стороннюю папку в репозиторий на гитхаб?

Tags: github, git-bash

Как запушить стороннюю папку в репозиторий на гитхаб? Мне кажется что это не сложный вопрос, просто интересует последовательность комманд, пушу через Git Bash

Comment: Что означает "сторонняя папка"?

Comment: Ну, тобишь у меня есть локальный репозиторий который уже связан с репозиторием на гитхабе. И я хочу другую папку, никак не связанную с этими репозиториями. И я хочу как-то запушить эту папку в уже существующий репозиторий на гитхабе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Гит отслеживает только ту папку, в которой находится .git. Всё, что вне ее, в данный репозиторий  не попадает. Придется копировать

В линуксе, может быть, можно сделать небольшим костылем через симлинк.

*ПС. Смысл такой процедуры не понятен.*

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Да после этого я тоже не особо вижу смысла своего вопроса. Но, буду знать больше инфы

Answer (score -1):

Слишком поздний ответ конечно, но надеюсь, что эта инфа пригодится начинающим , как и мне пригодилась ;)

Меня очень выручила эта статья: http://studyjavascript.blogspot.com/2017/10/github.html

По ней можно быстро и легко сделать необходимые действия.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: по ссылке говорится совсем не о том